# UnHandledRejection ¿por que?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Recién me surgió un problema al implementar mis propias promesas con Firebase y me arroja el error `UnHandledRejection`. Cree diferentes métodos para leer, guardar o modificar la base de datos en Firestore, el problema es la promesa que cree para el método guardar.

Este es mi código:

```
var method = {
  set: function (obj) {
    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      var db = firebase.firestore().doc("db/doc");
      db.get().then(function (res) {
        var data = res.data();
        var exists = _.find(data.users, {
          name: obj.user.name
        });
        if (exists === undefined) {
          db.set({
            users: _.concat(data.users, obj.user)
          });
          resolve({
            status: 200,
            message: "success"
          });
        } else {
          reject({
            status: 403,
            message: "This user already exist"
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
};
var save = method.set({
  user: {
    name: "Promise",
    lastname: " Handled"
  }
});
if (/* ... */) {
  save then(function (res) {
    if (res.status === "success") {
      console.log(res);
    }
  }).catch(function (e) {
    if (e.status === "error") {
      console.log(e)
    }
  });
}
```

La función `_.concat` y `_.filter` son de Lodash

El error sucede cuando inserto un usuario nuevo, me tira el error del usuario ya existe sin que este realmente exista en el documento pero aun así lo añade y la consola me tira `UnHandledRejection`, pero funciona correctamente cuando el usuario insertado si existe y no inserta nada

EDITADO:
Vera quiero extender un poco las funciones de firestore implementando mis propias promesas, para insertar un usuario nuevo o verificar si un usuario existe en un array multidimensional, que tengo guardado en un solo documento ubicado en la ruta `db/doc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El metodo   get() devuelve una operacion que puede ser fullfilled, pending o rejected , deberias devolver una condicion de rejected o error al hacer `.get()`

```
   var db = firebase.firestore().doc("db/doc");
                db.get().then(function (res) { 
                ...
                }catch(error =>{
                 console.log(error)
                });
```